# Nginx Proxy server - map to separate websites based on the path in the URL

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup a proxy server so that

```
proxy-server.com/app1  -->  website1.com
proxy-server.com/app2  -->  website2.com
```

1. There should be no redirection to the actual back-end application. User should only see `proxy-server.com/app[1/2]` in the URL.
2. All the static resources should load fine. For example a resource `/js/sample.js` from app2 should request from location `/app2/js/sample.js`
3. When I perform an action e.g. submit a form or navigate to another page in app2, request should prepend `/app2` so it is proxied to the right address

```
http {
  upstream webapp1 {
      server website1.com:443;
    }

    upstream webapp2 {
      server website2.com:443;
    }


     server {
          listen 80;
          listen 443 ssl;
          server_name   proxy-server.com;

          # certificate section

          location /app1 {
            proxy_pass https://webapp1/;
            proxy_set_header Host            website1.com;
          }

          location /app2 {
            proxy_pass https://webapp2/;
            proxy_set_header Host            website1.com;
          }
     }
}
```

The config only fixes point 1 but I am struggling hard to find a solution for the other two points mentioned above. I am looking for a clean solution, just to mention that I will try to avoid `if` statements or `sub_filter` module :)

Comment: The cleanest way is to use the same URI path on both the proxy and the proxied server. The application that are running on both web sites must be aware, that they are not deployed at the root of the domain. What are you using on `website1` and `website2`?

Comment: `website1` is a web application server which is the default to load. `website2` is a reporting application hosted on another different server. Ideally, all the requests should go to website1 unless there is `/app2` then I want everything from `website2`. I believe there is no elegant way to achieve the `/app2` fetch everything from `website2`. I will try to see if setting `/app2` as the root of the application will do the trick.

Comment: You can just change `location /app1` to `location /` then.